# iPhone app update via iTunes seems to cause it crashing 

Tags: ios, crash, uistoryboard

I just released my iPhone app update into the app store and appearently a lot of customers have problems with it crashing.  I have tested it a million times and not once did I get a crash.  I then updated the app from the app store on my on device and got the startup crash.  Can anyone help me identify the problem?

```
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         minecraft [354]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/BF192AFD-86D6-4C90-B577-EAABC5A13845/minecraft.app/minecraft
Identifier:      minecraft
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-04-21 13:59:43.892 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x312fe88f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31366259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   UIKit                           0x33e746e7 +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 439
3   UIKit                           0x33cab571 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 45
4   UIKit                           0x33b34893 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 223
5   UIKit                           0x33b2e8d7 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 235
6   UIKit                           0x33afcc6b -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1011
7   UIKit                           0x33afc70f -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 55
8   UIKit                           0x33afc0e3 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5827
9   GraphicsServices                0x343ec22b PurpleEventCallback + 883
10  CoreFoundation                  0x312d2523 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 39
11  CoreFoundation                  0x312d24c5 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 141
12  CoreFoundation                  0x312d1313 __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
13  CoreFoundation                  0x312544a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3125436d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
15  UIKit                           0x33b2da13 -[UIApplication _run] + 551
16  UIKit                           0x33b2ae7d UIApplicationMain + 1081
17  minecraft                       0x0000aac7 0x9000 + 6855
18  minecraft                       0x0000aa7c 0x9000 + 6780


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3477832c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37c33208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37c2c298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35184f64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x35182346 _ZL17default_terminatev + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x31366350 _objc_terminate + 140
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x351823be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3518244a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x3518381e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x313662a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x31254506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x31254366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  UIKit                           0x33b2da0c -[UIApplication _run] + 544
13  UIKit                           0x33b2ae76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  minecraft                       0x0000aac0 0x9000 + 6848
15  minecraft                       0x0000aa74 0x9000 + 6772

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x347683a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x36e45ea4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x36e45bc2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34778cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37beef36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37beecc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34778cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37beef36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37beecc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34768004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x347681fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x312d23ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x312d1124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3125449e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x31254366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x325e30f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37bf472e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x37bf45e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3fdfbd98      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fe07a5c
    r8: 0x001790c0    r9: 0x35185a4a     r10: 0x33edb8dc     r11: 0x001790c0
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fe07a50      lr: 0x37c3320f      pc: 0x3477832c
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
    0x9000 -    0x19fff +minecraft armv7  <3efcb8c4a3313f5ab6e4939f55c5696c> /var/mobile/Applications/BF192AFD-86D6-4C90-B577-EAABC5A13845/minecraft.app/minecraft
0x2fe08000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x3066a000 - 0x306b4fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x30984000 - 0x309b0fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x309b1000 - 0x309b2fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x309b9000 - 0x309bcfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x309bf000 - 0x309c1fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x309c9000 - 0x309d8fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30ab3000 - 0x30ab4fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x30ab5000 - 0x30abefff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30ac0000 - 0x30c3efff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x30c3f000 - 0x30c4bfff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x30c8e000 - 0x30c95fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x30e37000 - 0x30f0ffff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30f10000 - 0x30f17fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30f5d000 - 0x30f69fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31038000 - 0x3103efff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31119000 - 0x31119fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31245000 - 0x3135cfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x3135d000 - 0x31423fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x31424000 - 0x31429fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3142c000 - 0x31461fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x31462000 - 0x3161ffff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31620000 - 0x31625fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x31626000 - 0x3162bfff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x31772000 - 0x317affff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x3188a000 - 0x318c9fff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x318d1000 - 0x3196afff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3196b000 - 0x3196efff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31a65000 - 0x31a7bfff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x31a80000 - 0x31abcfff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31ac1000 - 0x31ac7fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x31aff000 - 0x31b73fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x31c6c000 - 0x31c77fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x31cec000 - 0x31cfdfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x31d17000 - 0x31d24fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x31d25000 - 0x31d65fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31ec5000 - 0x31f95fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x31faa000 - 0x31fc2fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31feb000 - 0x31ff0fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x32068000 - 0x32068fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x32186000 - 0x32188fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x324fe000 - 0x324fefff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x32522000 - 0x32531fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3253a000 - 0x32cf8fff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32cf9000 - 0x32d0dfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x32d0e000 - 0x32d58fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32d59000 - 0x32d76fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x32d77000 - 0x32ddafff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x32e0a000 - 0x32e0efff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32e42000 - 0x32f8bfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3308b000 - 0x3308efff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x3308f000 - 0x33090fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x3315f000 - 0x3315ffff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x331b2000 - 0x331fafff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x33359000 - 0x3335dfff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x336f8000 - 0x336fbfff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x33702000 - 0x33732fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3373b000 - 0x3391ffff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x339d7000 - 0x33a13fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33a16000 - 0x33a73fff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x33ae0000 - 0x33ae4fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x33ae5000 - 0x33ae8fff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x33af9000 - 0x33f9bfff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x33fe3000 - 0x33ff8fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x33fff000 - 0x34003fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x34004000 - 0x3400efff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x34017000 - 0x3413cfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3414c000 - 0x34195fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x3424f000 - 0x342f9fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x34306000 - 0x3431ffff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x343e7000 - 0x343f1fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3449a000 - 0x3449afff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x344d2000 - 0x344d6fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x34530000 - 0x34573fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x345a9000 - 0x345bafff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x345c5000 - 0x345d1fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x345d2000 - 0x34620fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x3466d000 - 0x3475bfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x34767000 - 0x3477dfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x347b8000 - 0x3483efff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x34858000 - 0x348b0fff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x348d0000 - 0x348d8fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x348dd000 - 0x34902fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x34928000 - 0x34937fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x34a7f000 - 0x34b41fff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x34cf9000 - 0x34d10fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x34d11000 - 0x34d17fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34e04000 - 0x350c5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x350c6000 - 0x3512afff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3517e000 - 0x35185fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x35186000 - 0x351c1fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35304000 - 0x35848fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35857000 - 0x35861fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x35862000 - 0x358d2fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x358d3000 - 0x358d7fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x358d8000 - 0x3590dfff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x3590e000 - 0x35953fff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x359ac000 - 0x359acfff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x359ad000 - 0x35b53fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x35c21000 - 0x35ca0fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35ca1000 - 0x35cf2fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x35d2a000 - 0x35d2efff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35d2f000 - 0x35d6dfff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35dd6000 - 0x35e1ffff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35e20000 - 0x35f11fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x35fa8000 - 0x35fccfff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x35fcd000 - 0x36073fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x360e1000 - 0x360e2fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x36193000 - 0x361dffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x361e0000 - 0x361f6fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x361ff000 - 0x36203fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x3620f000 - 0x3622ffff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x362dd000 - 0x362defff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x362df000 - 0x36302fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x36e39000 - 0x36e4ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x36ebd000 - 0x36f6afff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x36f7e000 - 0x36fbafff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3708a000 - 0x370c1fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3724d000 - 0x37291fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x37292000 - 0x3729afff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x373b4000 - 0x373bafff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x373c3000 - 0x373f7fff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x374af000 - 0x374c5fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x374cf000 - 0x374f2fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x374f3000 - 0x37720fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x37789000 - 0x37789fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x37869000 - 0x37888fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x37890000 - 0x378e1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x378f3000 - 0x378f4fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3795c000 - 0x37a33fff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37be4000 - 0x37be5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x37be6000 - 0x37c72fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x37c75000 - 0x37c79fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x37cad000 - 0x37cb0fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x37cb3000 - 0x37d2cfff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37d2d000 - 0x37d30fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x37e09000 - 0x37e41fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x37ecf000 - 0x37edefff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x37edf000 - 0x37ee5fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x37eea000 - 0x37f13fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x38097000 - 0x381dcfff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x381e3000 - 0x38291fff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
```

Comment: Have you tested it on a real iPod? Are all the crashes from the same device type (iPod) or same iOS (5.1?

Comment: iPod touch 4.  I have no idea on the last question.  I tested it via the simulator and nothing ever crashed.

Comment: Have you compared the update on the app store to the update as you created it to confirm it didn't get corrupted on the way?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have no idea what you mean.  It crashes on the app store; not on my device.  Surely apple would have noticed a startup crash?

Comment: @blake305 I thought you meant that when you developed the update and tested it, it worked. However, when you test that same update, in the same environment, dowloaded from the app store, it crashes. That suggests there could be a difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you understand the mechanics of an update as opposed to a fresh install.

A common issue that lapses through many developers;

NSUserDefaults remain the same from the previous version of your App, that could possibly get your App into a state you never really assumed / tested.

The entire sandbox of your app (Documents folder etc.) remains untouched - older files remain and are only overwritten by new versions if they actually exist.

For properly testing an update in an environment matching the real deal, one possible solution is to use a jailbroken device.

- First install the old version -- use the iPhone Configuration Utility for this step or an SFTP client
- Run it and make sure you trigger everything that could possibly write files to the device
- Then overwrite that old version with your new app version (make sure you do not delete anything, though) -- use an SFTP client for this step
- Run the app again and see what happens

You will need a jailbroken device because anything but direct (s)FTP upload will remove the old version first and replace it entirely with that new one. You do not want that to happen since that is not what happens when you update an app via the AppStore. Additionally, a jailbroken device will allow you to run AppStore builds without installing via AppStore, hence another issue that gets you closer to the real scenario.

Comment: When you say new app version files, do you mean the ipa?

Comment: You can not install an IPA (as is) on the device. The IPA is just a ZIP file. Extract it by renaming the extension to .zip and letting your finder do the rest. To install the new version on a jailbroken device, you are commonly copying the .app directly into the old location using your (s)FTP client of choice (e.g. CyberDuck).

Comment: Luckily, I have my SHSH Blobs saved for iOS 5.0.1, so I am downgrading now and will try your suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Considering it crashes via update and via new install, this doesn't help.

Comment: Ow that is new - you never mentioned that a fresh install also crashed, did you?

Comment: I found out the problem. It was appirater